# Open Android Device in Genymotion from Expo XDE gives error

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion, expo

I am using Expo XDE version 16.0.0 and I would like to test my app in the Android emulator. I am on a mac. I have installed Genymotion and have started the emulator as the expo.io (https://docs.expo.io/versions/v16.0.0/guides/genymotion.html) docs describes but I get the following error. I have no idea of what it means or how to fix it.

> Couldn't start project on Android: could not install *smartsocket*. listener: Address already in use ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon * error: cannot connect to daemon

I hope someone can help me on this one?

Comment: have the same prob

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was this on an Ubuntu 17.04

```
sudo apt remove android-tools-adb
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

it's possible you have adb and android-tools-adb installed

Answer (score 0):

After having spent a day figuring it out, I decided to go with using the Android emulation within genymotion. This is for Ubuntu (16.04).

- Download Android Studio & go into Tools > Android > AVD Manager.
- Download the SDK for whichever device & Android version you are going
  to use.
- Once downloaded, test the emulator is functional by clicking
  on the green play icon under 'actions' (far right in Virtual Devices
  screen).
- Open genymotion, settings > ADB > 'use custom Android SDK
  tools'. Select folder /*/Android/Sdk (wherever Android sdk is
  installed)
- Test by clicking on 'Start' in main genymotion screen.
  Open Expo XDE, load up the project & 'ctrl+d' to load on android
  device. It will start the installation of expo app.

Answer (score 0):

`vivid`response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512025/react-native-run-android-mismatch-version-adb-server-version) worked for me even on linux (he made it on OSX and I see [it works for windows too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959350/react-native-android-genymotion-adb-server-didnt-ack)).

Basically, you must check the versions of adb. Like:
`adb version`

And (using you real path)
`/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb version`

If they differ, replace `/usr/bin/adb` (first one) with the second one.

Other important things are that you must set the correct genymotion SDK. And make sure sdk & sdk tools must be present in the PATH variable.