# React Native: Emulator stuck on "loading from localhost:8081.."

Tags: android, react-native

[Screenshot from Android phone running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNtf9.jpg)

I am working on a react-native project and I run it on my android phone via USB debugging and the command "**react-native run android**".

It was working all fine but now even though the build is successful, the app gets stuck on the white screen "**loading from localhost:8081**". No changes were made in any of the app files.

I tried running the react-native demo app (using react-native init) and I still face the same issue.

Solutions I tried but still same issue:

1. **rm -rf node_modules && npm install**
2. **adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081**
3. Running it on Android Emulator from Android Studio.
4. Using the command **npm run android**

This is what shows up in the command line:

> lenovo@lenovo-Lenovo-ideapad-500S-14ISK:~/IRMSold$ react-native
>   run-android Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   /home/lenovo/IRMSold/node_modules (6ms) JS server already running.
>   Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew
>   installDebug)...
>
> Configure project :app  WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete
>   and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be
>   removed at the end of 2018. For more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Configure project :react-native-google-signin  WARNING: Configuration
>   'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and
>   'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information
>   see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is
>   ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.1. Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be
>   used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'"
>   from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle
>   Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> Configure project :react-native-vector-icons  WARNING: Configuration
>   'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and
>   'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information
>   see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is
>   ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.1. Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be
>   used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'"
>   from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle
>   Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> Task :app:installDebug  Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Lenovo
>   X3a40 - 6.0.1' for app:debug Installed on 1 device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s 66 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 65 up-to-date
>   Running adb -s 567bf688 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 Starting the app on
>   567bf688 (adb -s 567bf688 shell am start -n
>   com.irms/com.irms.MainActivity)... Starting: Intent {
>   cmp=com.irms/.MainActivity }

Kindly help me out, as I tried every other fix I could find online.

Comment: have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, problem is due to file handle limit. Once, I refresh the limit by following command, application starts to running without any problem.

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman shutdown-server
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 7):

Check if the device has the computer 8081 port forwarded by using

```
adb reverse --list
```

If you don't get any results you should
 create a reverse socket connection so your device can access the Metro Server

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

For some reason it still didn't work, so I pressed ENTER in this window ([Metro Bundler Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do3Pn.png))
and waited until it got to 100 % and then the app began displaying on my Phone.

Comment: This didnt help me

Comment: @mad_greasemonkey have you posted your own question? maybe there you could provide more context

Comment: Really weird but this pressing ENTER in metro bundler seems to do the trick

Answer (score 4):

My problem was with Watchman, which was somewhat tricky to identify because React Native happily bundled my app, transferred and launched the APK ! It kept kicking up an error about permissions on `/tmp/name-state` (where `name` is your name) so I had to `chmod 0700 /tmp/name-state` (to reduce permissions on that directory) then create a new app `npm react-native init appName` after that I started Metro again from another terminal (make sure you're in the new project directory) and ran `npm react-native start`. Then I could launch `appName` via `react-native run-android`.

Comment: I couldn't find the /tmp/name-state directory

Answer (score 3):

I'd been stuck per days and the problem was related to `Watchman` Permissions. See the verified solution and I hope this help someone

[Homebrew Permissions for Watchman on Muti-user Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978254/homebrew-permissions-for-watchman-on-muti-user-mac)

Comment: This solved the problem for me, on macos.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by uninstalling watchman. Could be an issue with installing it on M1 or something but it worked immediately after.

brew uninstall watchman

Answer (score 2):

You should waiting the state of package server to run perfectly. Until "Loading dependency graph, done.". If doesn't you will be stuck in loading from localhost 8081.

Answer (score 2):

solutions,

1. solution -> restart machine, it'll work but later u will get the issue again
2. solution -> watchman watch-del-all
3. solution ->

- echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
- echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
- echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
- watchman shutdown-server

4. solution -> if nothing works

- rm -rf node_modules
- npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.1. Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used. To suppress this warning, **remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.**

Comment: There is no such line in my build.gradle file which says '23.0.3'. However there was one with '23.0.1'. I did remove that line. Still the warning persists.

Comment: The build.gradle file was in /android/app

Comment: Try this: Delete the android folder in your directory and do "react-native upgrade"

Comment: I tried this. I got a sdk directory not found error so I added a local.properties file with the path and so the build was successful. However same issue. The screen is stuck at "loading from localhost:8081". This came up during the build: E/adb: adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
12:00:34 E/adb: * daemon started successfully

Comment: are you sure you are using the latest adb version? i want you to open your terminal and type this command. "adb devices". Comment back with the response.

Comment: List of devices attached 
567bf688 device

Comment: run these two commands.


"adb kill-server" and 
"adb start-server"

 Re-open the terminal and do "react-native run-android".

Comment: I did this. E/adb: adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
still present during the build. Build is successful but again same issue.

Comment: this link will help you with adb version mismatch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512025/react-native-run-android-mismatch-version-adb-server-version

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your 8081 port is already in use.

Try the first solution in here
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting

$ sudo lsof -i :8081
$ kill -9

Comment: This didnt help me either

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my experience

On android emulator `react-native run-android` was freezing at loading. While the same was running on iOS simulator. In my case I enabled debug js remotely on iOS simulator and found that i had supplied string value to a Boolean property.Once i corrected the issue it ran on android emulator.

Lesson Learnt : Android build are not that forgiving so run with ios and fix any errors you get on debugger that might lead to freezing of your emulator at Loading. from 8081

Answer (score 1):

There could be several cases where you can't connect to the debugger:

The device and host machine definitely should be on the same network. Either connect your mobile to your PC's network or your pc to the mobile hotspot.
In some cases on real devices, you might need to run adbe reverse command:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Uninstall the app, stop the packager, and restart the packager with reset cache option:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

And then, run it on the device again.

shake your device and in the menu choose dev settings

in the debug server host & port for device section enter your pc ip address via port 8081 like this: `192.168.1.3:8081`

Answer (score 1):

Killing the process which was already running on port 8081 worked for me

In Windows-

> netstat -ano | findstr :8081

> tskill TypeyourPID

Thanks, @luttius

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by closing the terminal that was running Metro and running the Android project again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to list of devices
3. Wipe data of the device causing issue.
4. Then restart the npm server and open on andoid.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could fix this by "Switching it (MacBook Pro) off and on again". I am sorry to not being able to provide more info on why this fixed it. Unfortunately a case of it does work (again) but I have not clue why...