# Homebrew Permissions for Watchman on Muti-user Mac

Tags: macos, react-native, permissions, homebrew, watchman

I have two users on my Macbook Pro running macOD Mojave 10.14.2 - one for work and one for personal.

I set up React Native on both users installing the react native cli & watchman

`brew install watchman`

`sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`

This worked and I was able to run the local server with `npm start`

I tried doing the same on the other user but was not able to install watchman with homebrew due to permissions issues.

I ran the following

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin $(brew --prefix)/*`

And that fixed it. I was once again able to run the local dev server.

---

Except now when I went back to my other user, I was not able to run the server again.

I get the following error when running `npm start`

`Loading dependency graph...libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: open: /usr/local/var/run/watchman/yev-state: Permission denied`

`Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=null, signal=SIGABRT, stderr= libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: open: /usr/local/var/run/watchman/yev-state: Permission denied`

I tried running `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin $(brew --prefix)/*` again which didnt fix it this time.

I also looked up how to configure Homebrew for multi-users macs and found [this short article](https://medium.com/@energee/install-brew-for-multiple-users-65af2444df5c)

I created a user group called "brew", added both my work and personal users to it and ran the following:

`sudo chgrp -R brew $(brew --prefix)/*`

`sudo chmod -R g+w $(brew --prefix)/*`

Still no dice.

I am not able to get it where I can freely user homebrew or run the dev server (due to watchman permissions error) on both users. I have to "fix" the permissions issue every time I change users.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `/usr/local/var/run/watchman` directory needs to have permissions `2777` so that any user can create their own state directory inside:

```
sudo chmod 2777 /usr/local/var/run/watchman
```

In addition, watchman performs some sanity checks to see if the state directory looks like it might have compromising permissions; I suspect that your very broad recursive `chmod` and `chown` calls are triggering that, so I'd recommend this as a very safe albeit disruptive thing to do assuming that other users have a working watchman:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/*
```

Comment: this did it! thank you for your help and explanation

Comment: You saved my life. I'd been stuck per days haha

Comment: Save my day too. I updated mongodb with brew but it also updated watchman... After a computer restart the new version was malfunctioning and producing this issue

Comment: Thank you   
Now It's working 

Comment: I get no such file or directory for the first command

Comment: The above paths didn't exist for me, but this fixed it:

sudo chmod 2777 /opt/homebrew/var/run/watchman/ && sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/run/watchman/*