# Watchman looking to opt/homebrew/root-state and can't access it

Tags: django, homebrew, watchman

Im trying to run my Django server as I did lot of times before, but probably after update or so im receiving errors from watchman, specifically this one

```
Watchman warning: opendir(/opt/homebrew/var/run/watchman/root-state) -> Permission denied.
```

And its strange because from what I researched this folder should have restricted access.

So I have two folders there, user-state and root-state
[image: folder]

Its still running server when im starting it, but throwing bunch of those errors in terminal so im just curios why its even watching in this dir.

After deleting all watching paths its starts looking in this path again.

Comment: try idea in here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978469/791609

Comment: @chenrui, I trued it, not helping(

Comment: same error msg?

Comment: yep, nothing changed